# How to Save a file in internal storage outsystems

Tags: outsystems

I need to save and open the PDF file in other mobile application to share the PDF via other apps.

I am generating a PDF file and I want to save that file in the internal memory and I am using Open Document action to open the application in external applications.

But I am getting a error in Save File action. Anyone help me to achieve this.

Thanks!

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLAH2.png) and this is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AdSuYYhRPZigXsvm14ZqVtNBQt05JSNi/view?usp=sharing) for `oml` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the file system [forge component](https://www.outsystems.com/forge/component-overview/68/filesystem).

Reference: https://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/50696/how-to-save-uploaded-file-as-physical-file-on-file-server-etc/